# Specflow - Scenario outilne with data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

I had a series of scenarios that look like this:

```
Given these receipts:
| Amount | Date       | Company         |
| 1000   | 2016/10/25 | One Company     |
| 1200   | 2016/10/20 | Another Company |
| 1500   | 2016/10/13 | My Company      |
And delay is 15
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be 20

Given these receipts:
| Amount | Date       | Company         |
| 1000   | 2016/10/25 | One Company     |
| 1200   | 2016/10/20 | Another Company |
| 1500   | 2016/10/13 | My Company      |
And delay is 30
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be 15

Given these receipts:
| Amount | Date       | Company         |
| 1000   | 2016/10/25 | One Company     |
| 1200   | 2016/10/20 | Another Company |
| 1500   | 2016/10/13 | My Company      |
And delay is 45
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be 10
```

So I learned about `Scenario outline` and I tried to make one for the above scenarios but had trouble putting in the receipts for obvious reasons:

```
Given these receipts: '<receipts>'
And delay is <delay>
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be '<dateOfPayment>'

Examples:
| delay | dateOfPayment | receipts                               |
| 15    |    20         | | Amount | Date       | Company     |  |
                        | | 1000   | 2016/10/25 | one company |  |
                        | | ..............................    |  |
```

`Given` that I want the same collection of, in this case, `receipts` for all `scenarios` in my `Feature` how can I declare a *table* that will be passed at the place of `'<receipts>'` in the `scenario outline`

Maybe, should I proceed with a different approach?

---------------------------------- EDITED --------------------------------

Maybe something like this could work (but It is not implemented in `Gherkin`):

```
Given these receipts: '<receipts>'
And delay is <delay>
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be '<dateOfPayment>'

Examples:
| delay | dateOfPayment | 
| 15    |    20         | 

Placeholder: '<receipts>'
| Amount | Date       | Company         |
| 1000   | 2016/10/25 | One Company     |
| 1200   | 2016/10/20 | Another Company |
| 1500   | 2016/10/13 | My Company      |
```

Comment: If the 'receipts' datatable data is constant across scenarios, you should keep it where you have in your original scenarios. And just put the 'delay' and 'dateOfPayment' in the scenario outline examples. But if the receipts data changes across scenarios this would not work. What is the dependency of the three companies in the datatable?

Comment: company is only an information in this example, it could be another date (issue date, due date).

Comment: @Grasshopper so I have to repeat the table for every scenario? It seems like that could be factorized somehow, maybe creating another scenario with only a given that pass the table as parameter. 
Maybe something like [this](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/FeatureContext/) (without using the feturecontext that is mentioned in that link)?

Comment: @Grasshopper I edited my question to show a possible solution, but I know it does not work yet (not implemented in `Gherkin`)

Comment: Can you use each line of the 'receipts' across all scenarios into single examples in a scenario outline?

Comment: the domain requires a collection of  receipts, so I cant''t

Comment: How about a comma delimited string for the receipt amount, date, company in each example of scenario outline -                         | delay | dateofpayment |  amount  |                date               |  company    |  | 15 | 20 | 1000,1200,1500 | 2016/10/25,2016/10/20,2016/10/13 | One Comp, Another Comp, My Comp |  --- You can split them in your step defs. Yeah it is a messy solution...

Comment: That would be a nice solution to provide different tables as we do with delay and other variables.

Comment: @Grasshopper, please check my answer below. Out of curiosity, does it work with Cucumber? With Specflow it works nicely!

Comment: It will work perfectly. That is what I had pointed out in my first comment. The Background thing is an additional benefit...

Comment: I hadn't understood your first comment, sorry!

Comment: No problems... As long as it works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this silly idea: Given that the receipts does not change I could maybe provide to the `Scenario Outline` a Given with the actual `table` rather than a `placeholder`

And it worked:

```
Scenario Outline: payment
Given these receipts:
| Amount | Date       | Company         |
| 1000   | 2016/10/25 | One Company     |
| 1200   | 2016/10/20 | Another Company |
| 1500   | 2016/10/13 | My Company      |
And delay is '<delay>'
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be '<dateOfPayment>'

Examples: 
| delay | dateOfPayment |
| 15    | 20            |
| 30    | 10            |
| 45    | 5             |
```

If you are, as I am, working in `.Net` with `Specflow` and `c#` specflow will generate this method for the `Given`with the `table`:

```
[Given(@"these receipts:")]
public void GivenTheseReceipts()
{            
    ScenarioContext.Current.Pending();
}
```

Don't worry, just add the `table` parameter, and the `table` will be passed as parameter as it does with a normal scenario:

```
[Given(@"these receipts:")]
public void GivenTheseReceipts(Table table)
{
    var receipts = table.CreateSet<Receipt>(); // you can even create a set given you have defined the Receipt class
}

public class Receipt
{
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
}
```

------------------------- EDITED -------------------------------------

It seems as it would have also worked with  `Background`:

```
Background: 
Given these receipts:
| Amount | Date       | Company         |
| 1000   | 2016/10/25 | One Company     |
| 1200   | 2016/10/20 | Another Company |
| 1500   | 2016/10/13 | My Company      |

Scenario Outline: payment
And delay is '<delay>'
When I calculate date of payment
Then Date of payment should be '<dateOfPayment>'

Examples: 
| delay | dateOfPayment |
| 15    | 20            |
| 30    | 10            |
| 45    | 5             |
```

Now, it's only  a matter of style.

Notice also that `Background` will be called before all other `scenarios` you may have in your `Feature` file.

Comment: This is valid Gherkin and will work with Cucumber and SpecFlow. The table is part of the Scenario Outline, so will be the same for each Example.

Answer (score 1):

`Scenario Outline` does not support table substitution.

You could, however, use:

`| delay | dateOfPayment | rcpt1Amnt | rcpt1Date | rcpt1Cmpny | rcpt2Amnt | recpt2Date | ...
|  15   |        20     |  1000     | 2016/10/25| One Company|  1200     | 2016/10/20 | ...`

Comment: It could be a solution, still it repeat the table in every single `example` and it is that what I want to avoid.

Comment: Please check my answer below. Out of curiosity it works with Cucumber-jvm? With Specflow it woks nicely!

Comment: I misread your original question @sabotero - your solution is the right way to go.

Comment: I just find it weird having to consume a data table  by creating an external class. Can't we just consume it as a arrayList or Map in specflow as we did in cucumber?